# html inside javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have some JavaScript code to display values from a mysql database.

```
columns: [
    { text: 'Taal', datafield: 'taal', width: 50},
    { text: 'Titel', datafield: 'titel', width: 690 },
    { text: 'Website', datafield: 'sitenaam', width: 180 },
    { text: 'Ingezonden Door', datafield: 'gamer_int', width: 150 },
    { text: 'Datum', datafield: 'datum', width: 100 }
]
```

When we look at the first column named `"Taal"` the mysql database contains a value like `eng_ico.png`. What I want is something like this so the results display that image.

```
columns: [
    { text: 'Taal', datafield: "<img src=\"http://www.site.nl/images/" 'taal' "\">, width: 50},
    { text: 'Titel', datafield: 'titel', width: 690 },
    { text: 'Website', datafield: 'sitenaam', width: 180 },
    { text: 'Ingezonden Door', datafield: 'gamer_int', width: 150 },
    { text: 'Datum', datafield: 'datum', width: 100 }
]
```

I cannot get this right. Don't know what I am doing wrong. I tried the `" . 'taal' . "` like in php but also no success.

Comment: `text: 'Taal', datafield: '<img src="http://www.site.nl/images/' + taal + '"/>', width: 50},` ?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, your string didn't have an ending speech mark, and the concatenation is done slightly different to PHP, using `+` instead of `.` (also I'd use single quotes to remove the need for escaping with backslashes)

```
'<img src="http://www.site.nl/images/'+taal+'">'
```

Comment: `"` = speech mark/double quote/quotation mark, `'` = single quote/apostrophe

Comment: Aaah, that makes sense... Never seen it called that before :P

Comment: He is confused in quotes. :|

Comment: Still no succes. I have -  { text: 'Taal', datafield: '<img src="http://www.gamepedia.nl/images/' + 'taal' + '">', width: 50}, - But i get no image.

Comment: @user2959441 Why the semicolon before the first `+` ? You have `'<img src="gamepedia.nl/images/'; + 'taal' + '">'` which should be `'<img src="gamepedia.nl/images/' + 'taal' + '">'` (no `;`)

Comment: That seems to be something stackoverflow adds because it is nog there in my code. I copy pasted it... { text: 'Taal', datafield: '<img src=\"http://www.site.com/images/' + 'taal' + '\">', width: 50},

Comment: What's the code that deals with it, the img might be properly stored as a string, and it's how you're outputting it that's the problem. Add that output code to the original question

Answer (score 0):

You have used quotes wrongly. See the following code

```
columns: [
    { text: 'Taal', datafield:'<img src="http://www.site.nl/images/'+taal+'">', width: 50},
    { text: 'Titel', datafield: 'titel', width: 690 },
    { text: 'Website', datafield: 'sitenaam', width: 180 },
    { text: 'Ingezonden Door', datafield: 'gamer_int', width: 150 },
    { text: 'Datum', datafield: 'datum', width: 100 }
]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is what i have now. Tried different sollutions... -  { text: 'Taal', datafield: '<img src="http://www.site.nl/images/'+taal+'">', width: 50} - no succes however...

Comment: @user2959441 You don't want the `;` - instead of ending `taal+'">';,` it should be `taal+'">',`